# Class WebClient does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```java
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

But I received the following error:

> ```
> Error:(6, 9) java: cannot find symbol
>  symbol:   class WebClient
>  location: class Main
> ```

I tried to search for the error on the web. I got 404.

Comment: Did you check your class-path to make sure that the package is visible. Is this maven/gradle? Did you actually link the jar?

Comment: Paked have red color, and don't can find it on web

Answer (score 2):

Above mentioned code is working for me

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(page.asText());
    }
}
```

gradle Dependency

```
  compile group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'com.springsource.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit', version: '2.6.0'
```

Comment: A have Failed to download  for any packedj

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'WebClient'